# Probability of difference between sets that are both dependent on a stochastic variable.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I'm reviewing some statistics for my exams and have a hard time figuring out what exactly the meaning of the question and solution is:

The variables are $X\sim exponential(2)$ and $X\sim exponential(2)$, and they are both independent

The probability that should be found is:
$P(\{X\le 1\}\backslash\{Y\le 1\})$

And i know the solution is $(1-e^{-2})e^{-2}$

How do you arrive at this solution, and more detailed - how do you rewrite the probability into something tractable.

Comment: Hint: $A\setminus B=A\cap B^c$

Comment: Yup, that's what i missed - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have:

$$\mathbb{P}(\{X\leq 1\}\setminus \{Y\leq 1\})$$
$$=\mathbb{P}(\{X\leq 1\}\cap \{Y >1\})= \mathbb{P}(X\leq 1)\mathbb{P}(Y>1)$$ and now it is just a matter of calculating the integrals. The last equality follows because $X,Y$ are independent.